# SuperSearch Module Install Creates 1044 Error

Tags: database, supersearch, mysql, database-error, super-admin

I've just attempted to install SuperSearch 2.2.3 on EE 2.9.2 and receive a a database 1044 error:

Access denied for user 'db######'@'%' to database 'db202322_##########'
It then goes on to list the Levenschtein function where it errored in the SuperSearch install code in upd.super_search.php.

I've attempted to grant all privileges to the user but cannot string together a query that works. Perhaps because I'm not a root admin or superuser? But I am a Super Admin in the CP...

Please advise if you can. I've also curious as to why the username and database are the same...specific version of the database for that user?

Answer (score 0):

Your database user does not have the required permissions to install a function into the database. Try increasing the permissions of that user.
Particularly, you need to make sure the CREATE ROUTINE permission is granted.

Comment: This is what I figured. Thank you. I have attempted to increase the permissions of that user but am limited to trying to do that as that user. As you can see in the original post, my queries are not allowed. How can I create a root user to alter permissions of other users or determine which user might have that root ability?